# Selected cell no longer highlighted after applying cellpainting in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to StackOverFlow and this is my first question, so please do not be to hard to the newbie I am if the questions is not formulated according to the Stack Overflow standards.

I am calling the `CellPainting` event on a `DataGridView` in order to format some cell text (the text contains HTML tags and I am changing the font of these tags). I managed to apply the formatting and to display it in the datagridview but calling the cellpainting event changes the behaviour of the datagridview as follows:

1. When I select painted cells (I am only painting those cells containing tags), the selected cells are not highlighted in blue. It looks as if the selection background color is not applied, even if I am defining it in the code.
2. The text stretches (space between characters is increased). I already tried to change the typography but it did not help.

Does anyone know how I can make the selection appear and how I can avoid text stretching? I will be grateful to anyone who could help.

I copied the code of the cellpainting event at the bottom of this question.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Regards,

Laurent

PS: I am loading the data from a sqlite database.

```
//Creating the table of string where the formatting should change 
Debug.Print(e.Value.ToString());
string[] cellFormattingStr = _tagRegex.Split(e.Value.ToString());
Debug.Print(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, cellFormattingStr));

//Get cell formatting as it is
DataGridView currentDGV = (DataGridView)sender;

Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + 1, e.CellBounds.Y + 1, e.CellBounds.Width - 4, e.CellBounds.Height - 4);
//Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Location, e.CellBounds.Size);

using (Brush backColor = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor), gridBrush = new SolidBrush(currentDGV.GridColor))
{
    using (Pen gridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush))
    {
        //Erase the cell
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColor, e.CellBounds);

        //Draw the gridlines
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom);

        e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;

        //Draw the inset highlight box.
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, newRect);

        int cellBoundX = e.CellBounds.X + 2;
        int cellBoundY = e.CellBounds.Y + 2;
        int lineLengthAfterIns = 2;

        for (int cfs = 0; cfs < cellFormattingStr.Length; cfs++)
        {
            Brush txtColor = null;
            if (cellFormattingStr[cfs].StartsWith("<"))
                txtColor = Brushes.Red;
            else
                txtColor = Brushes.Black;

            //Creating the table of words for the part to be formatted
            string[] fmtdWords = cellFormattingStr[cfs].Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            for (int w = 0; w < fmtdWords.Length; w++)
            {

                //Check the size of words and add it to the xbound to see if it exceeds size of cell. If yes, xbound is reset to initial value and ybound increased to the size of a new line
                SizeF wdDim = e.Graphics.MeasureString(fmtdWords[w], e.CellStyle.Font);

                lineLengthAfterIns += (int)wdDim.Width;
                Debug.Print(fmtdWords[w] + "; " + lineLengthAfterIns + "; " + e.CellBounds.Width);
                if (lineLengthAfterIns >= e.CellBounds.Width - 4)
                {
                    cellBoundX = e.CellBounds.X + 2;
                    cellBoundY += (int)wdDim.Height + 2;
                    lineLengthAfterIns = 2;
                }

                e.Graphics.DrawString(fmtdWords[w], e.CellStyle.Font, txtColor, cellBoundX, cellBoundY, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
                cellBoundX += (int)wdDim.Width;
            }

        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a lool at [`e.PaintBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs.paintbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`e.Paint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs.paint(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Dear @Reza, Thank you for your reply. I am sorry that I am only reacting now but I  had to stop working on this project. e.paintBackground did the trick for the colour. Any idea about how I could avoid text stretching.

Answer (score 0):

before drawing the text, use:
e.PaintBackground(newRect, true);